# Typographic entities in WPF FlowDocument

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

Is it a way to add to FlowDocument content specific typographic symbols (dashes, greek symbols, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters